# Time complexity of simple linear regression in $L_1$ norm

Tags: regression, algorithms

I come from a computer science background. I'm considering simple linear regression using $L_1$ distance.

We are given points $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. We are interested in finding a line $f(x) = ax+b$, such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i - f(x_i)|$$
is minimized.

I did some initial literature search, and it seems people solve the problem using linear programming.
I am interested in finding the fastest algorithm in terms of the number of points. That is, I'm looking for references that looks like the following

> Simple linear regression in $L_1$ norm can be solved in $O(T(n))$ time,
>   where $n$ is the number of points.

Comment: I believe you'd get a faster answer in SE.

Comment: Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a $O(n^2)$ running time algorithm.

It is fairly easy to derive: There exists an optimal line that contains one of the given points (in fact, at least 2 points). There exists a $O(n)$ time algorithm to decide the best line that goes through a given point. Basically a weighted median computation. Together, it implies a $O(n^2)$ running time algorithm.

The first paper I know that uses this idea is the following.

> *Bloomfield,
>   Peter; Steiger, William*, [**Least absolute deviations
>   curve-fitting**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0901019), SIAM J. Sci.
>   Stat. Comput. 1, 290-301 (1980).
>   [ZBL0471.65007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0471.65007).

**Edit 1:**
[Using advanced tools from computational geometry, one can improve the running time to $\tilde{O}(n^{4/3})$](https://chaoxuprime.com/posts/2019-03-28-l1-linear-regression.html).

**Edit 2:**
There is a paper that gives a $O(n\log^2 n)$ time algorithm.

> *Megiddo, Nimrod; Tamir,
>   Arie*, [**Finding least-distance
>   lines**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0604021), SIAM J. Algebraic
>   Discrete Methods 4, 207-211 (1983).
>   [ZBL0517.05007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0517.05007).

There is another paper which I still have to verify, that explains $O(n)$ time is possible. In fact, it seems that $L_1$ linear regression in $d$ dimensions can be solved in $O(n)$ time if $d$ is a constant.

> *Zemel, Eitan*, [**An O(n) algorithm for the linear multiple choice knapsack problem and related problems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(84)90014-0), Inf. Process. Lett. 18, 123-128 (1984). [ZBL0555.90069](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0555.90069).